# Which pages don't have links pointing at them?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, wiki, sitepages

### Context

In SharePoint site pages, there is an option to see what pages have (internal) links pointing at them. From any site page, click the **Page** tab. In the **Page Actions** group, click **Incoming Links**. Now there is a report of pages that are linking your current page.

### Problem

To maintain a policy of *every page must be linked from another*, I need to occasionally search for pages that don't have links. As the content grows, this becomes increasingly difficult to determine which pages have **zero** links pointing to them.

### Question

> Is there a way to get a list of site pages with zero incoming links?